# Cannot properly set Flexbox div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have small problem with my code.
With small amount of text it looks like really good ( firefox / chromium - window maximized ):

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html, body { height: 100%; max-height: 100%; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; }

body > div:last-child > div { width: 100%; }

body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

body > div:first-child{
display: flex;
flex-grow: 0;
height: auto;
}

body > div:first-child > div{flex-grow: 1;}

body > div:last-child{
align-items: center;
background-color: black;
color: white;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
<div style="background-color: red;">Left</div>
<div style="background-color: green; text-align: center;">Center</div>
<div style="background-color: blue; text-align: right;">Right</div>
</div>
<div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
Start<br>
Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
End
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

But when I add: "Test(...)" x2 - I have a problem with height, which is by default set to auto.

Here's a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/)**.

Here's a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/5/)** with x2 text - this is my issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why adding a flex-basis value works, fixes the problem, but it does:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/5/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
body > div:last-child > div {
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
body > div:first-child {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
}
body > div:first-child > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
body > div:last-child {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    flex: 1 0 0; /* here */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Also, don't set elements to `display: flex` unless you actually need them to be flex containers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Can I have centered text vertically & horizonstally with your solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You used a lot of unnecessary CSS code.
See this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/6/)**.

I'm using this CSS to align the menu divs:

```
float: left;
width: 33%;
```

or you can try adding `z-index: 3;` to `body > div:first-child > div`
and also add `height: 20px;` to your menu.

**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/9/)**

**Update**

You may want to try this method: **[Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/KTgrS/)**

Comment: I know this method, but:

*I need 100% height for body and all content

*I nned overflow hidden for body and overflow auto for main div

Flexbox is what I need, but I have only issue with height and lots of line in main div ...

Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I added support in 100% height.

Comment: It's true, but i have overflow on main div, not on body, so the whole page is scrolled - with this change there's a problem main div must use the rest of page and flexbox solve this.

Comment: and you have 100% for container, so the height is 100% of container ( try add more lines ) height ( all text ) + top div height - this is great example to use flexbox - I think - Thanks for your time

Comment: Looks really good, but see the "Start" and see http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/10/ - there is no "Start" - visible ...

Comment: Hi, I found the answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8qm/23/
I need to wait some time to answer my question, so I will do it tomorrow.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

the top line gets shrinked because even you didn't specify it, the `body > div:first-child` **is** *shrinkable* because the default value of `flex-shrink` is `1`

add `flex-shrink:0` and you will resolve the problem

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kN2x4/13/

Comment: Reaaly nice, but I cannot see "Start". It is good when I remove some text. Can you fix this, please ?